# Content not being wrapped when being passed from App.js via props but is being wrappepd otherwise

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to create an invoice generator basic application, I have created an array of objects of the data in the App.js file which looks like this. If I pass the data from the App.js file using props, the "notes" part doesn't get wrapped, rather it overflows it's container.

```
import "./App.css";
import InvoiceItem from "./InvoiceItem";
import InvoiceList from "./InvoicesList";


function App() {
  const invoices = [
    {
      invoice: 13491,
    notes: "ndjdkjdkjdbkdbdkjbdkjdbkjb",
    name: "Rahul's tax filing",
    rate: 20,
    quantity: 10,
    total: 100,
      
    },
    {
      invoice: 1235,
    notes: "lorem ipsum",
    name: "jdndkjndkjnd",
    rate: 20,
    quantity: 5,
    total: 100,
      
    },
    {
      invoice: 1236,
    notes: "lorem ipsum",
    name: "jdndkjndkjnd",
    rate: 20,
    quantity: 5,
    total: 100,
      
    },
    {
      invoice: 1341,
    notes: "lorem ipsum",
    name: "jdndkjndkjnd",
    rate: 20,
    quantity: 5,
    total: 100,
      
    }
  ]
  return <div className="App">

    <InvoiceList invoicedata={invoices}></InvoiceList>
  </div>;
}

export default App;
```

This is where the content will be displayed, please note that I'm using Bootstrap aswell. However, if I type the content normally in the "notes" part it does get wrapped itself. How do I fix this?

```
import "./InvoiceItem.css";

function InvoiceItem(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container custom__width border border-2 rounded mt-2 mb-2">
      <div className="row border border-1 border-end-0 border-start-0 border-top-0">
        <div className="col-4">{props.invoicenumber}</div>
        <div className="col-8 margin__adjust">{props.addnotes}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="row mt-4">
        <div className="col-6">Item Name</div>
        <div className="col-2">Rate</div>
        <div className="col-2">Quantity</div>
        <div className="col-2">Total</div>
      </div>
      <div className="row mt-4">
        <div className="col-6">{props.name} </div>
        <div className="col-2">{props.rate}</div>
        <div className="col-2">{props.quantity}</div>
        <div className="col-2">{props.total}</div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default InvoiceItem;
```

Comment: ohh it simply just install prettier to format your code automatically.

Comment: I already have it installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use map to loop through the array containing your data like this:

```
<div className="row border border-1 border-end-0 border-start-0 border-top-0">

{invoicenumber && invoicenumber.map(item => {
  return (
    <div className="col-4">{item.invoice}</div>
    <div className="col-8 margin__adjust">{item.notes}</div>
)}
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, I'll get that done but will that help with text wrapping?

Comment: have you add the prettier as your default formatter on your settings.json (if you vs code user) ?

link for reference : https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#default-formatter

Comment: yes I have it there